# WordPress white screen of death

Tags: migration

I recently migrated the site from a subdomain back to the main domain using WP All-in-One Migration Tool. The migration was successful and I can see the wp-admin panel just fine and even view the site while logged in.

But... when logging out the visitors just see the white screen of death. I have tried every fix in the book on Google, any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What do your logs say (debug.log, PHP log, webserver log)?

Comment: Have you tried erasing your browser cache completely? Also, I'd search for the subdomain address in the database to see if there are any forgotten values from the imigration (and change them accordingly).

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin? When logged in, you'd be bypassing that cache, which is why it would work.

Answer (score 0):

so I can try to give you some tips but I cannot guarantee it will work- not sure what you have tried yet, best option, in this case, is to first find the cause of this and then go from there to fix it. In order to figure out what the problem is you can either-

- check the logs( probably in your /wp-content/ folder )
- since you have access to the admin panel you can try disabling all plugins and check if it fixes it
- you can also switch themes and see if that causes it

Some additional links and resources that might help you: [link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/askrubi/), [link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/), [link](https://wordpress.org/support/article/common-wordpress-errors/).

Answer (score 0):

To see the error message, set the DEBUG flag to true in *wp-config.php* and refresh the page.

```
if ( ! defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
}
```